# Drop a table in dolphindb

Tags: mysql, dolphindb

In MySQL, I can use DROP TABLE command to completely remove the data in a variable. In dolphindb, which command can allow me to do the same thing？

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "DROP TABLE command to completely remove the data in a variable" ?????

Answer (score 0):

t=table(1 2 3 as x, 4 5 6 as y)

```
db = database("C:/DolphinDB/Data/test")

saveTable(db,t);


dropTable(db,`t);
```

There is an extensive documentation for dolphin DB:
http://www.dolphindb.com/help/